# play sound in python Mac

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a game and I want a mp3 file to playing in the background when I run the code, plus I want another mp3 file to run when I collect coins in the game. How can I do that in Mac (if it differs)? I tried using playsound but it doesn't seem to work for me. I also tried subprocess but it plays the sound without executing the code. The game is using tkinter btw.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give an example of what you have tried, and what error you are getting. Thanks1

Comment: there is no error for play sound the sound just doesn't play.

Comment: Yes. but can you give an example of what you have tried?